# Adding onfocus and onblur within PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried inputting the onfocus and onblue event within a form within PHP on a WordPress website, and cannot fathom the best way to do so:

Here is the form code within 'general'template.php' which is a WordPress file:

```
$form = '
    <form name="' . $args['form_id'] . '" id="' . $args['form_id'] . '" action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">
        ' . $login_form_top . '
            <input type="text" name="log" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_username'] ) . '" class="input" value="Username" size="20"  />
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_password'] ) . '" class="input" value="Password" size="20" />
        ' . $login_form_middle . '
        ' . ( $args['remember'] ? '<label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_remember'] ) . '" value="forever"' . ( $args['value_remember'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ) . ' /> ' . esc_html( $args['label_remember'] ) . '</label>' : '' ) . '
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ) . '" class="button-primary" value="' . esc_attr( $args['label_log_in'] ) . '" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="' . esc_url( $args['redirect'] ) . '" />
            <a class="btn btn-theme" href="/register/">Register</a>
        ' . $login_form_bottom . '
    </form>';
```

I want to add the onfocus and onblur events to the Username and Password fields.

```
 onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Username') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Username'; } "
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: add those attribute on those field.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim I have just made an edit to my post, which should make things a little more clearer! :)

Comment: you are getting syntax error with the updated one?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim yeah, the error is 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Username' (T_STRING)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes using backslash. So, you need to use this way:

```
onfocus="if(this.value  == \'Username\') { this.value = \'\'; } " onblur="if(this.value == \'\') { this.value = \'Username\'; } "
```